# How to use php filter for "contact page" in drupal 6?

Tags: 6, theming, input-formats

How can I set the PHP filter for the "contact page" in Drupal 6?
I want to insert some PHP code in the description of the contact form page.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your want to enable php code filter for user end, it could be dangrous for your site.
Any one can perform some dangerous activity by adding php code.
or if you want to alter the "contact form" then you have to use  "hook_form_alter".

Comment: Just to clarify, Giovanni wants to alter the description of the contact page, not the message body of the contact form, therefore the user end will not be able to use PHP code.